# Rmpfr list variables: how are vectors coerced?

Tags: r

Can someone explain what's happening in this example code?  I have a function which does a calculation loop and as always, wanted to initialize my output vector instead of incrementing it each time thru the loop.

```
Rgames> library(Rmpfr)
Rgames> foo<-rep(NA,5)
Rgames> foo
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
Rgames> rfoo<-mpfr(rep(NA,5),20)
Rgames> rfoo
5 'mpfr' numbers of precision  20   bits 
[1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Rgames> for(jj in 1:5) {
+ foo[jj]<- mpfr(jj,10)
+ rfoo[jj]<-mpfr(jj,10)
+ }
Rgames> rfoo
5 'mpfr' numbers of precision  10   bits 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
Rgames> foo
[[1]]
'mpfr1' 1

[[2]]
'mpfr1' 2

[[3]]
'mpfr1' 3

[[4]]
'mpfr1' 4

[[5]]
'mpfr1' 5
```

I don't understand why, apparently, the existing non-mpfr vector `foo` is not only coerced to a list, but then each time through the loop, the new value is inserted into `foo[jj]` as a list, giving me an unpleasant "list of lists" .  The `mpfr` vector `rfoo` does what I expected I'd get in both cases.  (I checked, and if I do not initialize, and put something inside the loop like  `foo<-c(foo,mpfr(jj,10))` I do get a result equivalent to `rfoo`)

Comment: What's `mpfr`?  Is it in a particular package?

Comment: Almost. `Rmpfr` is a package that offers vector- and matrix-like objects with higher decimal precision than ordinary floating point numbers. It's and acronym for "Multiple Precision Floating-Point Reliable".

Comment: Oops.  I always give the package, but forgot this time.  My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is the same thing that would happen if you were working with lists instead of `mpfr` objects.  For example, as follows.  I believe this makes sense because S4 objects are stored in a similar way to lists, but I'm not an S4 expert.

```
> foo <- rep(NA,2)
> foo
[1] NA NA
> foo[1] <- list(1)
> foo
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] NA
```

I believe that what happens is that the original atomic vector gets coerced to a list to be able to include the object that you've asked to put there.  I can't find any documentation about that right here; I think it's discussed in Chambers's book but don't have that at hand.

One can easily recreate this behavior using `S3` methods as well; first the `S3` methods to create a new class:

```
mynum <- function(x) {structure(as.list(x), class="mynum")}
print.mynum <- function(x) { cat("My numbers are:\n")
                             print(do.call(paste, x), quote=FALSE) }
```

Here's what happens if you start with an atomic vector:

```
> (foo <- rep(NA, 2))
[1] NA NA
> foo[1] <- mynum(1)
> foo
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] NA
```

and here's what happens if you start with the `mynum` vector:

```
> (rfoo <- mynum(rep(NA, 2)))
My numbers are:
[1] NA NA
> rfoo[1] <- mynum(1)
> rfoo
My numbers are:
[1] 1 NA
```

Comment: To start down the S4 rabbit hole, try: `showMethods("[<-")` and then `getMethod("[<-", c("mpfr", "ANY", "missing", "mpfr"))`, `getAnywhere(".mpfr.repl")`, etc.

Comment: No point in 'going there' until you actually need it, but when you do, those commands will be your bread and butter ;)